# sbt, how to maintain own libraries?

Tags: maven, sbt, semantic-versioning

Let's assume we have three projects (version in brackets):

```
A (0.0.1)
B (0.0.1), depends on A (0.0.1)
C (0.0.1), depends on B (0.0.1)
```

*C depends on A & B.*

Now we want to use this libraries as dependencies in our new project (D).
So we add deps:

```
C (0.0.1)
```

Then we understand that A is missing some function, so we create it and increase version of A to 0.0.2 and add this dependency to D:

```
C (0.0.1)
A (0.0.2)
```

Sbt will complain about this deps when compiling D, something like

> [warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
>   [warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted: [warn]  *
>   A:0.0.1 -> 0.0.2

So i wonder, what's the best practice for cases like these? I thought that sbt knows about semantic versioning and understands that 0.0.1 is compatible with 0.0.2 and won't show any warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SBT: is it wise to fix eviction warnings of library dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520273/sbt-is-it-wise-to-fix-eviction-warnings-of-library-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 ways:

1. When you increase `A` version, you also increase the version of `A` that `B` depends on:

   `B (0.0.1), depends on A (0.0.2)`
2. Add `SNAPSHOT` to version:

   `A (0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)`

   `B (0.0.1), depends on A (0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)`

Also semantic versioning is not a strict rule and you can't rely on it completely because not all developers adhere to it that's why I think sbt warning is legal.